# sql job and datetime parameter

Tags: sql, scheduled-tasks, getdate

Another developer created a stored procedure that is set up to run as a sql job each month.  It takes one parameter of datetime.  When I try to invoke it in the job or in just a query window I get an error `Incorrect syntax near ')'`.  The call to execute it is:

```
exec CreateHeardOfUsRecord getdate()
```

When I give it a hard coded date like `exec CreateHeardOfUsRecord '4/1/2010'` it works fine.  Any idea why I can't use `getdate()` in this context?  Thanks.

Comment: actually I was incorrect.  the parameter is smalldatetime not datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters passed with Exec [must either be constants or variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx). GetDate() is classed as a function. You need to declare a variable to hold the result of GetDate(), then pass it to the stored procedure.

> The supplied value must be a constant
>   or a variable; you cannot specify a
>   function name as a parameter value.
>   Variables can be user-defined or
>   system variables such as @@spid.

Answer (score 1):

by looking at [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

```
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
    { 
      [ @return_status = ]
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var } 
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value 
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
                           | [ DEFAULT ] 
                           }
```

you can only pass in a constant value or a variable or the DEFAULT clause

try it out:

```
create procedure xy_t
@p datetime
as
select @p
go

exec xy_t GETDATE()
```

output:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: OP mentions datetime vs.smalldatetime, however the data type doesn't really matter, it will fail before it gets that far. Try `exec xy_t '10'+'2'` using my sample procedure and you get `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '+'.`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing Convert(varchar, GetDate(), 101)

Comment: you can not pass an expression into a stored procedure, see my example code.  trying your answer results in: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Convert'.`

Answer (score 0):

Using Km's code here is a way to do it

```
create procedure xy_t 
@p datetime 
as 
select @p 
go 

declare @date datetime

set @date = getdate() 

exec xy_t @date
```